# Need java project example with Authentication and Authorization

Tags: java, authentication, github, authorization

I am developing a new java project. I have written the code in my own way and felt that it is not a standard model and difficult to maintain.Now I want to convert it to a standard model.

I need the standard java project models with permission filter, authorization 
hander, interface/implement models. I want to follow that model and implement my project.

Any simple architecture or github project will helps a lot.

P.S: I am using tomcat,postgres,redis,struts2.

Comment: Shall i know why my question is down voted?

Comment: I do think that this is a **google** question and it is far from being a specific technical one.

Comment: I was searching a model projects in google and couldn't find exact project to follow.So asked here.Shouldn't we ask these type of question here?. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **Struts2**, I do recommend you to start with these two 30 minutes tutorials:

- https://www.programcreek.com/2010/03/struts-2-tutorials-sample-application-login-module
- https://www.concretepage.com/struts-2/struts-2-annotation-simple-login-example